# Edit a select by adding a new custom option in prestashop 1.7 contact form

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add an option to a select element in the contact form in prestashop 1.7.2.4.

I could not find any option in the backend, so i tried to edit the contactform.tpl manually, but unluckily it didn't work. Then new option does appear in the form, but when selected and submitted, the page says to chose an option for the argument (i'm assuming it doesn't find a corresponding value somewhere in the backend and results in an error).

I also tried to find a table in the database where i could have added my custom option, but still couldn't find anything.

Do you know if there's any way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean:

Go to this menu: "Shop parameters" >> "Contacts"

and add your option